# Python: How to consolidate all calender items into a single csv file?

Tags: python, csv, outlook

Could anybody suggest a method to 'extract' all outlook calender items into a csv file per each work week (e.g. 10 weeks back)?

Say point of reference is current week.

As an example output:

```
Week 10
Meeting 1
Meeting 2
Meeting 3

Week 9
Meeting A
Meeting B
Meeting C
```

and so on till current week, i.e. Week 1.

I have little/zero experience 'communicating' between python-outlook.

Appreciate your education..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/ they also have python bindings so you can use the library directly from within python.